# trainig lstm keras model on a tpu on colab i get an error: Failed to serialize message

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

i can't train a lstm keras model on tpu of google coab

it run on cpu put it is very slow
'''
    import tensorflow as tf

```
def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(400001, 50, input_length=100,weights=[emb_matrix], trainable=False))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

  model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
  )
  return model

with tpu_strategy.scope(): # creating the model in the TPUStrategy scope means we will train the model on the TPU
  model = create_model()
model.summary()

model.fit(x=X_train_indices, y=Y_train_oh, validation_split=0.25)
```

'''
i get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-23871a130a73> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x=X_train_indices, y=Y_train_oh, validation_split=0.25)

11 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     94       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 96   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     97 
     98 

RuntimeError: Failed to serialize message
```

link to notebook [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FR6yXPYfWxVrjvew1JsM2rNw-vVSqgfr?usp=sharing)